# How can i hide a div on clicking it which is already automatically hiding after some seconds?

Tags: jquery

I have a div. This div is automatically hiding after 5 seconds with delay. But i want the user himself can hide it by clicking on it before the specified time period of 5 seconds is passed - like we see in phpmyadmin when some action is occurred. I am hiding it by fadeOut() method. This method is working fine when div itself hides after 5 seconds but fadeOut() is not working when clicking event occurs. If I use hide() then it works. So why can not i use fadeOut() on click event? Here is my code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".msg_wrapper").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);

    $(".msg_wrapper").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(500); // does not work, but hide() works, why?
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT : use jQuery [clearQueue](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/) [>= jQuery v1.4] method to cancel a delay :

```
$(function() {
    $('.msg_wrapper').delay(5000).fadeOut(500).on('click', function () {
        $(this).clearQueue().fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KY7TZ/1/

Or if you prefer to work with pure Javascript's setTimeout method :

```
$(function() {
    var $msg = $('.msg_wrapper'),
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $msg.fadeOut(500);
        }, 5000);

    $msg.click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $msg.fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KY7TZ/

Comment: Great! That worked very well. I just needed clearQueue() in jquery chain before fadeOut(). Both jquery and javascript solutions are good. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just keep in mind that "clearQueue" really clears all the queued calls on your element, so if you have, for any reason, to delay other jQuery calls on it, it will remove these too !